# TypeError: registerForPushNotificationsAsync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm working on a project in react native using expo and graphql, where I need to have push notifications. I've never done this before, so I looked at two examples/tutorials on how to do this. I added my own code to the basic parts of the set-up, but I'm getting an error saying `TypeError: registerForPushNotificationsAsync is not a function. (In 'registerForPushNotificationsAsync()', 'registerForPushNotificationsAsync' is undefined)`. In my `navigation.tsx` document:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/elements';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";

import { RootStackParamList } from './types';
import { useNotifications } from "../hooks/useNotifications";



const prefix = Linking.createURL("/");
const linking = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
  /*config: {
    screens: {
      Home: "home",
      Settings: "settings",
    },
  },*/
};

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {
const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>()
const {registerForPushNotificationsAsync, handleNotificationResponse} =
 useNotifications();

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: true,
      }),
    });

    const responseListener =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
        handleNotificationResponse
      );

    return () => {
      if (responseListener)
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
...
)
```

I'm still learning and getting used to TypeScript, so I'm struggling to figure out what the problem is. I tried looking at [TypeError: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)
 to figure out what the issue could be, but none of the suggestions seemed to be the problem, and I can't use `useNotifications` on it's own instead of `registerForPushNotificationsAsync` because that would break the rule of hooks. Does anyone know why I am having this problem? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

useNotifications.tsx

```
import { Alert, Linking, Platform } from "react-native";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { openSettings } from "expo-linking";
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const REGISTER_DEVICE_MUTATION = gql`
mutation registerDevice($input: DeviceRegisterInput!) { 
   registerDevice(input: $input) {
     token
  }
}
`;

const UNREGISTER_DEVICE_MUTATION = gql`
mutation unregisterDevice($token: NEString!) { 
    unregisterDevice(token: $token) {
    token
  }
}
`;

export const useNotifications = async() => {
  const [registerDevice, { data: registerDeviceData, error, loading }] = useMutation(REGISTER_DEVICE_MUTATION);
  const [unregisterDevice, { data: unregisterDeviceData, error:unregisterDeviceError, loading:unregisterDeviceLoading }] = useMutation(UNREGISTER_DEVICE_MUTATION);
  const user= await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');

  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async (alertUser?: boolean) => {
    if (Device.isDevice) {
      if (!user) return; 
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }

      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        if (alertUser) {
          Alert.alert(
            "Error",
            "To enable Push Notifications please change your settings.",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
              },
              {
                text: "Open Settings",
                onPress: openSettings,
              },
            ]
          );
        }
      }
      const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      const previousToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PushToken');

      if (previousToken && previousToken === token) {
        return console.log('Push Token exist');
      }
  
      if (previousToken && previousToken !== token) {
        await unregisterDevice({variables: { token: previousToken } });
  
        console.log('Push Token update');
      }

      registerDevice({variables: { 'userId': user,'token': token } });
      if (registerDeviceData.registerDevice) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('PushToken', token);                 
      }
      else {
        throw new Error("User doesn't allow for notifications");
      }
    } 
    else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }
  };
  // This listener is fired whenever a notification is received while the app is foregrounded
  const handleNotification = (notification: Notifications.Notification) => {
    // could be useful if you want to display your own toast message
    // could also make a server call to refresh data in other part of the app
  };

  // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
  const handleNotificationResponse = (
    response: Notifications.NotificationResponse
  ) => {
    const data: { url?: string } = response.notification.request.content.data;

    if (data?.url) Linking.openURL(data.url);
  };

  return {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync,
    handleNotification,
    handleNotificationResponse,
  };
};
```

Comment: `useNotifications` is an async function, so it returns a `Promise<{handleNotifications, handleNotificationResponse, registerForPushNotificationsAsync}>`, not an object with those functions inside it.